# Can you spend one production unit to offset population loss from plague cubes on a population 0 location?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

At the end of a game in Pandemic Legacy Season 2, population is adjusted for locations which have supply houses and plague cubes (up and down, respectively). The manual specifically mentions the case where a location has both - the population does not change.

You can also spend production units to increase the population of a location. 1 population for 1 unit, except if the location has a population of 0, in which case 2 units are needed to bring it back to population 1.

Consider a case where I have a plague cube on a location with a current population of 1. The plague cube will decrease the population by 1, making it a 0 population location. I want to spend production units to keep it at 1, but do I need to spend 1 unit or two? That is, does the population adjustment from plague cubes happen before population adjustment from spending production units? Or do they happen at the same time?

As part of the game end, the manual has the adjustment due to plague cubes as step 1 and the adjustment due to spending production units as step 4 , so I'm guessing they happen in a distinct order and I would need to spend 2 units. I couldn't find any clarification though.

Comment: I believe that you are correct in your last paragraph in that you do the steps in order and when you get to step 4 the population is 0 and you need to spend 2 production units to get the population back to 1. I don't see what more clarification you need so I'm not putting this in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Pandemic Legacy, always follow the rules in exact order, use the rule book as a check list. You can not progress through to subsequent steps until you have completed the entirety of your current step.

During end game, if the population decreases to 0 during step 1, then that city is forsaken. It remains at population 0 until you (may) spend 2 production points during step 4.

If you want to prevent a drop in population, then build a supply centre on that location during the game, as end game Step 1 is holistic in regards to supply centres and plague cubes.

When in doubt over any of the rules, do what is in the least interest of the players.